# DBA first day in a new job - check backups and security - How? what else should be checked?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, backup, restore, security

Generally when I start in a new environment, I tend to check where are the backups, when the last full was taken, when was the last restore applied and I check the security too.

The way I do this is via T-SQL.

> Check the backups

```
        ;with Radhe as (
            SELECT  @@Servername as [Server_Name],
            B.name as Database_Name, 
            ISNULL(STR(ABS(DATEDIFF(day, GetDate(), MAX(Backup_finish_date)))), 'NEVER') as DaysSinceLastBackup,
            ISNULL(Convert(char(11), MAX(backup_finish_date), 113)+ ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),MAX(backup_finish_date),108), 'NEVER') as LastBackupDate
            ,BackupSize_GB=CAST(COALESCE(MAX(A.BACKUP_SIZE),0)/1024.00/1024.00/1024.00 AS NUMERIC(18,2))
            ,BackupSize_MB=CAST(COALESCE(MAX(A.BACKUP_SIZE),0)/1024.00/1024.00 AS NUMERIC(18,2))
            ,media_set_id = MAX(A.media_set_id)
            ,[AVG Backup Duration]= AVG(CAST(DATEDIFF(s, A.backup_start_date, A.backup_finish_date) AS int))
            ,[Longest Backup Duration]= MAX(CAST(DATEDIFF(s, A.backup_start_date, A.backup_finish_date) AS int))
            ,A.type
            FROM sys.databases B 

            LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset A 
                         ON A.database_name = B.name 
                        AND A.is_copy_only = 0
                        AND (A.type = 'D')  --'D' full, 'L' log 

            GROUP BY B.Name, A.type

        )

         SELECT r.[Server_Name]
               ,r.Database_Name
               ,[Backup Type] = r.type 
               ,r.DaysSinceLastBackup
               ,r.LastBackupDate
               ,r.BackupSize_GB
               ,r.BackupSize_MB
               ,F.physical_device_name
               ,r.[AVG Backup Duration]
               ,r.[Longest Backup Duration]

           FROM Radhe r

            LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily F
                         ON R.media_set_id = F.media_set_id

            ORDER BY r.Server_Name, r.Database_Name
```

> For checking the security:

[Server Level and Database Permissions by Kenneth Fisher](https://sqlstudies.com/2015/02/25/using-sp_dbpermissions-and-sp_srvpermissions-v6-0/)

> Checking the restores:

```
DECLARE @dbname sysname, @days int
SET @dbname = NULL --substitute for whatever database name you want
SET @days = -30 --previous number of days, script will default to 30
SELECT
 rsh.destination_database_name AS [Database],
 rsh.user_name AS [Restored By],
 CASE WHEN rsh.restore_type = 'D' THEN 'Database'
  WHEN rsh.restore_type = 'F' THEN 'File'
  WHEN rsh.restore_type = 'G' THEN 'Filegroup'
  WHEN rsh.restore_type = 'I' THEN 'Differential'
  WHEN rsh.restore_type = 'L' THEN 'Log'
  WHEN rsh.restore_type = 'V' THEN 'Verifyonly'
  WHEN rsh.restore_type = 'R' THEN 'Revert'
  ELSE rsh.restore_type 
 END AS [Restore Type],
 rsh.restore_date AS [Restore Started],
 bmf.physical_device_name AS [Restored From], 
 rf.destination_phys_name AS [Restored To]
FROM msdb.dbo.restorehistory rsh
 INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bs ON rsh.backup_set_id = bs.backup_set_id
 INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.restorefile rf ON rsh.restore_history_id = rf.restore_history_id
 INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf ON bmf.media_set_id = bs.media_set_id
WHERE rsh.restore_date >= DATEADD(dd, ISNULL(@days, -30), GETDATE()) --want to search for previous days
--AND destination_database_name = ISNULL(@dbname, destination_database_name) --if no dbname, then return all
ORDER BY rsh.restore_history_id DESC
GO
```

> Replication:

```
--first thing - go to the publisher DB and find out the distributor server and DB
sp_helpdistributor

-- go to the distributor server and DB found above and run the following:
sp_replmonitorhelppublication null
```

> Mirroring:

```
--==============================================================================
-- query that shows the current state of each database in the mirroring
--==============================================================================
  SELECT   db_name(sd.[database_id])              AS [Database Name]
          ,sd.mirroring_state                  AS [Mirror State]
          ,sd.mirroring_state_desc             AS [Mirror State] 
          ,sd.mirroring_partner_name           AS [Partner Name]
          ,sd.mirroring_role_desc              AS [Mirror Role]  
          ,sd.mirroring_safety_level_desc      AS [Safety Level]
          ,sd.mirroring_witness_name           AS [Witness]
          ,sd.mirroring_connection_timeout AS [Timeout(sec)]
    FROM sys.database_mirroring AS sd
    WHERE mirroring_guid IS NOT null
    ORDER BY [Database Name];
```

> ALWAYS ON

I use [the script by Rudy Panigas](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/96887/)

```
--  Always On Status Report
--
-- This script will show the status of the Alway On replication status

SELECT DISTINCT
primary_replica as 'Primary Server',
[endpoint_url] as 'End Point URL',
primary_recovery_health_desc as 'Primary Server Health Status',
secondary_recovery_health_desc as 'Secondary Server Health Status',
operational_state_desc as 'Operational State',
connected_state_desc as 'Connection State',
recovery_health_desc as 'Recovery Health',
synchronization_state_desc as 'Synchronization State',
database_state_desc as 'Database State',
JOIN_state_desc as 'Join State',
suspend_reason_desc as 'Suspended Reason',
availability_mode_desc as 'Availability Mode',
failover_mode_desc as 'Failover Mode',
primary_role_allow_connections_desc as 'Primary Connections Allowed',
secondary_role_allow_connections_desc as 'Secondary Connections Allowed',
create_date as 'Date Created',
modify_date as 'Date Modified',
[backup_priority] as 'Backup Priority',
role_desc as 'Role Type',
last_connect_error_description as 'Last Connection Error',
last_connect_error_timestamp as 'Last Connection Error Time',
last_sent_time as 'Last Data Send Time',
last_received_time as 'Last Data Recieved TIme',
last_hardened_time  as 'Last Hardened Time',
last_redone_time as 'Last Redone Time',
log_send_queue_size as 'Log Send Queue Size',
log_send_rate as 'Log Send Rate',
redo_queue_size as 'Redo Queue Size',
redo_rate as 'Rate of Redo',
filestream_send_rate as 'Filestream Send Rate',
last_commit_time as ' Last Commit Time',
low_water_mark_for_ghosts as 'Low Water Mark for Ghosts'
FROM sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states

JOIN sys.availability_replicas
ON sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states.group_id =  sys.availability_replicas.group_id

JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_cluster_states
ON sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states.group_id =  sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_cluster_states.group_id

JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states
ON sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states.group_id =  sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states.group_id

JOIN sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states
ON sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states.group_id =  sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states.group_id

WHERE operational_state_desc IS NOT NULL
AND database_state_desc IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY [endpoint_url] DESC

-- Testing section
/*
-- Suspend replication from primary
ALTER DATABASE [AdventureWorksLT2008] SET HADR SUSPEND

-- Resume replication from secondary
ALTER DATABASE [AdventureWorksLT2008] SET HADR RESUME

-- Force a manual failover of replication with data loss. MUST EXECUTE ON SECONDARY SQL SERVER
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [AG-AdventureWorksLT2008] FORCE_FAILOVER_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS;

-- Force a manual failover of replication with NO data loss MUST EXECUTE ON SECONDARY SQL SERVER
--- YOU MUST EXECUTE THE FOLLOWING SCRIPT IN SQLCMD MODE.
--Connect VDV1OPS03

ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [AG-AdventureWorksLT2008] FAILOVER;
GO

--- YOU MUST EXECUTE THE FOLLOWING SCRIPT IN SQLCMD MODE.
--:Connect OPSDBSRV

ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [AG-AdventureWorksLT2008] FAILOVER;
GO

*/
```

> Log Shipping:

[Different ways to monitor Log Shipping for SQL Server databases](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2553/different-ways-to-monitor-log-shipping-for-sql-server-databases/)

**Question:**

Other than the above, are there other things I should be checking when starting on a new environment as a matter of priority?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I wrote the free (and open source) [sp_Blitz](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/) for this exact reason.

People kept handing me SQL Servers and going, "You're the DBA, you manage this thing." I needed something that could quickly analyze stuff like:

- Databases that hadn't been backed up or checked for corruption
- Unsupported builds of SQL Server
- Dangerous trace flags and database settings
- Bad sp_configure options

Just run it, no parameters required, and you'll get a prioritized health check. Priorities 1-50 are things you want to jump on right away, and priority 51+ are things to take a note of for later.

For support or to contribute code, head to the Github repo at [FirstResponderKit.org](http://firstresponderkit.org).

Comment: Love your comments in the code  /* If the server has any databases on Antiques Roadshow, skip the checks that would break due to CTEs. */

Comment: Heh heh heh... I had a lot of fun with that proc, and I try to make it interesting for folks who like reading source code.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old one and there's already plenty of great content to help a DBA out when taking over a new DBA role. However, an important addition I'd make to this list is to validate your inventory.

Nothing is worse than fixing all of the SQL Servers you thought you had, only to have a random SQL Server you've never heard of crash next week. You'd be surprised how often this happens.

Consider running something such as dbatools.io (Find-DbaInstance), Idera SQL Server Discovery,  or the Microsoft MAP Toolkit. Be sure to save the results somewhere, and true it up as as servers are built or decommissioned.